# Guardar valor incrementado dentro de uma funçao click JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

Tenho a seguinte função.

```
 $('#proximo').click(function() {
         token = localStorage.getItem("userToken"); 

          page =0;

            var e = document.getElementById("idSelecionaSize");
            var size = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

            var search = $location.search();
            var page = search.page||page;
            var size = search.size||size;
            var sort = search.sort||'type,desc';

             page++;


            $http({
                 method: 'GET',
                 url: '/user/distritosPaginacao?page=' + page + '&size=' + size + '&sort=' + sort
            }).then(function(response) {
                $scope.distritos = response.data.content;
                $scope.number= response.data.number;
                $scope.page = response.data.totalPages;
                $scope.sort = sort;
                $scope.size= response.data.size;

            });

        });
```

Quando o usuário clicar no botão o page vai receber o valor 1 porém no segundo click o botão volta a ter o valor 1. Gostaria que, ao clicar, o valor fosse 2, 3, 4, ... e assim sucessivamente.

Como fazer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está atribuindo o valor "0" à variável "page", em seguida está redeclarando ela (imagino que aqui seja outra variável) e no final está incrementando ela em 1.
Para funcionar, sua variável precisa ser declarada em escopo global, ou seja, fora deste método. Depois de declarada e iniciada com o valor "0" fora deste método, ela vai manter o último valor atribuído.

Ex.:

```
var pageIndex = 0;

$('#proximo').click(function() {
         token = localStorage.getItem("userToken"); 

            var e = document.getElementById("idSelecionaSize");
            var size = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

            var search = $location.search();
            var page = search.page||pageIndex;
            var size = search.size||size;
            var sort = search.sort||'type,desc';

             pageIndex++;


            $http({
                 method: 'GET',
                 url: '/user/distritosPaginacao?page=' + page + '&size=' + size + '&sort=' + sort
            }).then(function(response) {
                $scope.distritos = response.data.content;
                $scope.number= response.data.number;
                $scope.page = response.data.totalPages; // Sugiro trocar o nome desta variável para evitar ser confundida com a variável page acima
                $scope.sort = sort;
                $scope.size= response.data.size;

            });

        });
```